# Simple PHP Regex

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, routes

I am setting up a Zend_Route (but it is still just a regex) and I wish to match a url like

```
/en/experience/this-is-my-name-and-the-last-is-1-of-id-123456.html
```

So I want to grab the

```
this-is-my-name-and-the-last-is-1-of
```

and the

```
 123456
```

I tried

```
\w{2}/experience/(.+)?-(\d+)\.html
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

It would be easy if the other way around e.g. if it was id the name

```
/en/experience/123456-this-is-my-name-and-the-last-is-1-of-id.html
```

I could use

```
\w{2}/experience/(\d+)-(.+)\.html
```

But that is a cop out - so any advice on how to match original format?

Comment: Your regex works fine for me: http://www.rubular.com/r/Ou5N48bV2Q

Comment: So do you not want to match the `-id-` bit? Your example doesn't show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
/\w{2}/experience/(.+?)-(\d+)\.html
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
`/\w{2}/experience/(.+)?-(\d+)\.html`

zend route internally does this:
`preg_match('#^/\w{2}/experience/(.+)?-(\d+)\.html$#i', '/en/experience/this-is-my-name-and-the-last-is-1-of-id-123456.html', $matches);`

so, your pattern only matches with a slash on the beginning.